# Windows 10 Installation

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows 8.1. I have downloaded Windows 10 and then received the notice preparing for installation, Nothing else. So I did a restart on my computer and I dont think it ran or was installed. I tried to find out if it is installed but I am not computer savvy so could not figure it out. I did read from another site that I would be notified when installation will take place. What do I do? Wait or take my computer to a professional,

Answer (score 0):

The windows 10 UI is dramatically different, and the lack of startscreen is a givaway. You can hit <kbd>win</kbd> - <kbd>X</kbd> then go to system to check. That said, MS hasn't quite gotten the process totally smoothed out. Check to see if the update failed. If it did, then I'd try the following

In some cases I simply deleted the download and tried again

As per the [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3eyrre/fix_for_the_80240020_error_when_trying_to_install/) page that everyone refers to

1. Go into "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download" and delete everything in that folder.
2. Now, run the command prompt as an administrator. Type in "wuauclt.exe

If that fails, delete the folder (again), go to download the media creation tool, and tell it to upgrade.

If it *still* fails, go find a profrssional.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have backed up all your data and your Windows registration key, as recommended.

Then simply download the latest Windows 10 installation image to a USB stick from here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10
using a different, still functioning computer, boot your sick computer from the USB stick, reformat your HDD and select clean installation.